# Extract rows by id each time when it comes another value in other column

Tags: r

I need to extract rows by id each time when it comes another value in other column cause to save each of them to data frame as csv.

```
id_row  City      Date
1       Milan  13-01-2019 
2       Paris  14-01-2019
3       Paris  14-01-2019
4       Berlin 15-01-2019
5       Berlin 16-01-2019
```

So I need to create new data frames for each new date and city. For example: for Berlin, there would be two different dfs for both 15-01-2019 and 16-01-2019.

```
filename  <- paste("/Desktop/filename/data_", temp_city, "_", temp_date, "_", start_id, "_", end_id, ".csv")
```

Now, I need to write code which will extract id_row directly/automatically into filename.

Output should be:

```
data_ Paris _ 14-01-2019 _ 2 _ 3 .csv
```

2 to 3 - are ids.

Answer (score 1):

We can `split` the dataframe based on `City` and `Date` and separate the data into list of dataframes, remove the empty dataframes from the list. Use `lapply` and loop over each dataframe and create a path to write the dataframe

```
lst_df <- split(df, list(df$City, df$Date))
lst_df <- lst_df[sapply(lst_df, nrow) > 0]

lapply(lst_df, function(x) write.csv(x, paste("/Desktop/filename/data",x$City[1], 
           x$Date[1], paste0(x$id_row, collapse = "_"), ".csv", sep = "_")))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` solution would be

```
# Create example data.table
dt <- data.table(id_row = c(1,2,3,4,5), 
             City = c("Milan", "Paris", "Paris", "Berlin", "Berlin"),
             Date = c("13-01-2019", "14-01-2019", "14-01-2019", "15-01-2019", "16-01-2019"))

# Group by City and Date, concatenate id_rows
dt <- dt[, paste0(id_row, collapse = "_"),
         by = list(City, Date)]

# (optional) set the name of the new column
setnames(dt, "V1", "ids")

# Return the filenames
dt[, paste("data", City, Date, ids, sep = "_")]
# [1] "data_Milan_13-01-2019_1"   "data_Paris_14-01-2019_2_3" "data_Berlin_15-01-2019_4" 
# [4] "data_Berlin_16-01-2019_5"
```